# Failed large file upload to Google Cloud Storage from Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, busboy

What I need to achieve is to allow a user to upload files to Google Cloud Storage from his browser: the user select a file, a FormData containing the file is created and sended to a Cloud Function. The Cloud Function then sends the data to Google Cloud Storage. This piece of code works well for small files. But when I try to upload bigger files (30mo is the size I usually want to send) I have this error

`PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large`

It looks like cloud function check the size of the uploaded data even if try to make the limit bigger. Is there any way to go beyond the 10mo limit ?

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

app.post("/upload-my-file", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await authentChecker(req.headers)
        const busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});

        busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename) => {
            const storage = new Storage();
            const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket-name');
            const newBucketFile = myBucket.file(filename);

            //I don't write a temp file on disk, I directly upload it
            file.pipe(newBucketFile.createWriteStream())
            .on('error', function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            })
            .on('finish', function() {
                console.log("finish")
            });

        })
        // Triggered once all uploaded files are processed by Busboy.
        // We still need to wait for the disk writes (saves) to complete.
        busboy.on('finish', async () => {
            res.send();
        });
        busboy.end(req.rawBody);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [github](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/1291) you need to add "extended: true" for bodyParser.json. Please see [body-parser module documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) for more about this.

bodyParser = {
json: {limit: '50mb', extended: true},
urlencoded: {limit: '50mb', extended: true}
};

OR

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb', extended: true}))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '10mb', extended: true}))

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this solution doesn't work, I still have the same "PayloadTooLargeError" error. I tried what people suggested on this github page. It looks like they may not be using Cloud Function which should explain why they don't have those limitations